# Some strings are missing after space when retrieved

Tags: string, forms, jsp

I've made a board and it retrieves String data from DB.

when the retrieved Strings are put in form, strings after space are just gone.

Here is my code.

```
<c:forEach items="${detail}" var="dto">
    <form id="editposting" name="editposting" action="updatepost.bo" method="post">
        No
        <input type="text" readonly id="no" name="no" class="form-control" value=${dto.no}>
        <br> Writer
        <input type="text" readonly id="uname" name="uname" class="form-control" value=${dto.name}>
        <br> Author
        <input type="text" id="author" name="author" class="form-control" value=${dto.author}>
        <br> Sentence Summary
        <input type="text" id="summary" name="summary" class="form-control" value=${dto.summary}>
        <br> Full review
        <textarea rows="10" id="fullrev" name="fullrev" class="form-control">${dto.fullrev}${dto.name }${dto.summary }</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" id="pdate" name="pdate" class="form-control">
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:history.back();">Cancel</button>
        <c:if test="${sessionScope.uid==dto.name||sessionScope.uid=='admin'}">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
        </c:if>
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

So when I type "Hello World" in Author form, and post it.

It goes into DB and it is fine.

When I click the posting that I just wrote from the board, I can see only 'Hello' in Author label.

But if I put the same code in textArea attribute, I can see 'hello world' fine.

Answer (score 1):

While i was doing my `jsp/servlet` project i also faced this problem. I solved this problem.

You can try changing `value=${dto.no}` to `value="${dto.no}"`